# Embedded documents only return id and created at

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making an api to store a practice that contains workposts. When I GET my practice I get the array of workposts but it only includes the id and created/updated at properties

This is my workpost schema

```
'use strict';

// Requirements
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Workpost Schema
const WorkpostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  workpost_name: { type: String},
  workpost_icon: { type: String},
  workpost_info: { type: String},
  created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
},{versionKey: false});

// Export the Workpost schema
let Workpost = mongoose.model('Workpost', WorkpostSchema);

module.exports.WorkpostSchema =  WorkpostSchema;
module.exports.Workpost = Workpost;
```

This is the Practice schema that uses it

```
'use strict';

// Requirements
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const WorkScheduleSchema = require('./workschedule-module').WorkScheduleSchema;
const WorkpostSchema = require('./workpost-module').WorkpostSchema;

// Practice Schema
const PracticeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  practice_name: {type: String, required: true},
  address: String,
  email: String,
  tel: String,
  workschedules: [WorkScheduleSchema],
  workposts: [WorkpostSchema],
  created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
},{versionKey: false});

// Export the Practice schema
let Practice = mongoose.model('Practice', PracticeSchema);

module.exports.Practice = Practice;
```

When I try to get the practice I get this:

```
address: "Some adress"
created_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.288Z"
email: "email@email.com"
practice_name: "Some practice"
tel: "00000473975832"
updated_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.288Z"
workposts: Array(2)
0:
created_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.291Z"
updated_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.291Z"
_id: "5c94f6eb1a0a6200128461d2"
__proto__: Object
1:
created_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.290Z"
updated_at: "2019-03-25T12:42:05.290Z"
_id: "5c94f7121a0a6200128461d3"
```

None of the other attributes are included in the return. I make a practice using the following code and return it with a simple get request

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
WorkPosts.find({_id: {$in: req.body.workposts}}, {_id:1}).exec( function (err, workposts) {
      if (err) {
        err.message = "Workposts not found";
        return next(err);
      }
      let practice = new Practice(req.body);
      practice.workschedules = workschedules;
      practice.workposts = workposts;

      practice.save((err, practice) => {
        if (err) {
          err.message = "Practice couldn't be saved";
          return next(err);
        }
        res.statusCode = 201;
        res.json(practice);
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "None of the other attributes are included in the return"? The only missing field in the output is `workschedules`. By the way: `      practice.workschedules = workschedules;` where does it come from? A global variable?

Comment: It comes from an other schema. But it works the same as workposts

Comment: Since you're referencing an objectID (workschedules), and you seem to be using mongoose, did you try using populate ? As you're doing GET, so populate seems to be useful for this case !